Send email in AfterUpdate of new record using the new record for merge fields
We have a record for which an email needs to be sent, but the sendEmail process is happening in the AfterUpdate of the triggerhandler.
The email template being used is a VF component/HTML one with a controller to access the required merge fields used in the template.
Are these fields available for merging in the AfterUpdate? Or are the fields only accessible once the save of the record is committed (ie when the AfterUpdate completes)?

The devil's in the details, I'm afraid. Email templates, like everything else, can only see what's already saved to the database. If you check out the Triggers and Order of Operation documentation, you'll see that step 7 is a temporary save. Anything you do after that, such as after triggers, will see any changes made up to that point. However, after triggers are still executed before assignment rules and other automations that may change the values of the record later. This means that if you're hoping to see the final "settled" form of the record, you may need to go asynchronous to ensure that the correct data can be pulled into the template. If you have no such automations, then the email template should be able to merge the correct values in the trigger.
